# Numbering multi-line records continuously in a list

Tags: bash, perl, shell, awk, sed

I am trying to re-number records in a file continuously after inserting or removing a record. The file looks like below, with > 100 records. If e.g. the 2nd record has been removed, all the following ones need to be re-numbered, so that there is no gap in sequence. Any idea how this can be done in e.g. bash or awk (or perl) ... also if it is just in theory.

record-file.txt:

```
#  filter rule1
FilterRule1.match_message_facility = MME_E
FilterRule1.match_message_process = -1
FilterRule1.match_message_host = -1
FilterRule1.not_matched_facility_to_log_to = MME_E
FilterRule1.max_time_since_last_match_secs = 300


# incoming files 
FilterRule2.match_message_facility = EXG
FilterRule2.match_message_event_severity = I
FilterRule2.match_message_host = -1
FilterRule2.not_matched_facility_to_log_to = EXG
FilterRule2.max_time_since_last_match_secs = 2000

# outgoing files  
FilterRule3.match_message_facility = EXG
FilterRule3.match_message_event_severity = I
FilterRule3.match_message_host = -1
FilterRule3.not_matched_facility_to_log_to = EXG
FilterRule3.max_time_since_last_match_secs = 14400

# outgoing files: included headers
FilterRule4.match_message_facility = EXG
FilterRule4.match_message_event_severity = I
FilterRule4.match_message_host = -1
FilterRule4.not_matched_facility_to_log_to = EXG
FilterRule4.max_time_since_last_match_secs = 900

...
```

Comment: what is a record here?

Comment: and what do you try that failed  (and which error) ?

Comment: @Vijay: One **record** is the lines with the **same** FilterRuleX number, e.g. all lines starting with **FilterRule2**.

Answer (score 2):

Read the input in the "paragraph mode", one record a time. Change the rule number to the value you keep in a variable, increment it for each record:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

$/ = '';                    # Read in the "paragraph mode".
my $record_id = 1;
while (<>) {
    s/^FilterRule[0-9]+/FilterRule$record_id/gm;
    $record_id++;
    print;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

awk to the rescue!

```
awk -vRS= -vORS="\n\n" '{gsub(/FilterRule[0-9]*/,"FilterRule"NR)}1'
```

numbers the records starting from 1 consecutively.

Comment: comments incorporated.

Comment: believe it or not, not putting a space between `-v` and `var=value` makes the script gawk-specific so it's best to just put a space in `-v RS= -v ORS='\n\n'` so it'll work with any awk.

Answer (score 0):

Removed the third record:

```
7> cat temp
#  filter rule1
Filterrule1.match_message_facility = MME_E
Filterrule1.match_message_process = -1
Filterrule1.match_message_host = -1
Filterrule1.not_matched_facility_to_log_to = MME_E
Filterrule1.max_time_since_last_match_secs = 300


# incoming files
Filterrule2.match_message_facility = EXG
Filterrule2.match_message_event_severity = I
Filterrule2.match_message_host = -1
Filterrule2.not_matched_facility_to_log_to = EXG
Filterrule2.max_time_since_last_match_secs = 2000


# outgoing files: included headers
Filterrule4.match_message_facility = EXG
Filterrule4.match_message_event_severity = I
Filterrule4.match_message_host = -1
Filterrule4.not_matched_facility_to_log_to = EXG
Filterrule4.max_time_since_last_match_secs = 900
>
```

Run the command:

```
perl -pi -lne '{$i++ if(/^#/);s/Filterrule./Filterrule$i/g;}' temp
```

Numbering will changed now and will be sequential.